# UICollectionView full width and height problem

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

UICollectionView width is not full width, One cell per row

> UICollectionView

```
private func setCollectionView() {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.register(ImageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}
```

> UICollectionView -> Constraint

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.leadingAnchor),
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.trailingAnchor),
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

> UIColletionViewCellSize

By adding `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

> ImageCollectionViewCell

```
class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
....
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return img
    }()
....
}
```

> ImageCollectionViewCell -> imageView Constraint

```
   addSubview(imageView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor),
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor),
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor),
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

> **UICollectionView FlowLayout Warning**
>
> The item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
>
> The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -44}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {44, 0, 34, 0}> collection view layout: .

**This is Keep Happening**

https://gph.is/g/EqNL8jr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UICollectionView Warning Fix

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never } 
    else { automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false }
```

> Scale to fill was giving bigger image than UIImageView size

```
    img.clipsToBounds = true
```